# subtract vector column from scalar in spark using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used Movielens 20 million dataset which contain file called rating .csv(UserId,MovieId,Rating) .I applied Alternating Least Square(ALS) which give output userId,FeatureVector in 10 parquet files . [Dimensinality Reduction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DdrF.png)
I want to make normalize for featureVector using z-score method.
I want to subtract vector(featureVector) from constant scalar 2.484 ,divide value into 1.8305 and save value in parquet files.[features column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luYgm.png)

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet")
sqlContext.sql("select features from df")
df.withColumn("output", "features" -2.484).show(20)
```

How to subtract vector from each value of scalar?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the features column?

Comment: features column is added to question .

Comment: I am not sure that I get what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a complete scenario with input and the desired output?

Comment: I added output of algorithm which give me parquet files.

Comment: so in your example features array has only one item? is this the case always?

Comment: I want feature column to change only but id not effect.

Comment: ok I understand that but the `features` column has one element or more?

Comment: features column has one element only like in image (feature column).

Comment: so you are trying to subtract 2.484 from all the items of `features`?

Comment: yes,but I can't read all data of features column from parquet file.I can read only 20 row using hive.please, can you provide me with code?

Comment: so essentially you need to subtract 2.484 from every row i.e: 4,507 - 2.484 = 2,023? Is that correct?

Comment: yes,I write df.withColumn("Column name", ((df("features")-constant1)/constant2))
andsave to parquet is df..write.parquet("file:///usr/local/data")  but give me error but give me requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (2): id, features
New column names (1): features

Comment: this is because `features` is of array type and hence you need to access a specific array item each time not the column itself with `df['features']`. You can try to access it with `(col('features').getItem(0) - constant1) / constant2`

Comment: can you provide me with correct code ,please?

Comment: hi what was the problem with the previous code? do you get any error?

Comment: same error appear " requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match. Old column names (2): id, features New column names (1): features".

Answer (score -1):

if you want to subtract 2.484 from each vector value you can try it

```
  import spark.implicits._
  import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{DenseVector, Vectors}
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val df = Seq(Vector(1.0,2.0,2.5,3.0,3.5)).toDF("features")

  val rdd: RDD[DenseVector] = df.select('features)
    .rdd
    .map(s => s.getAs[Seq[Double]]("features").toArray)
    .map(s => Vectors.dense(s.map(s => s - 2.3333)).toDense)

  rdd.take(10).foreach(println(_))
```

output:

```
[-1.3333,-0.33329999999999993,0.16670000000000007,0.6667000000000001,1.1667]
```

Comment: But give error "class DenseVector takes type parameters" how to solve it.I'm using spark 2.0.0.

Comment: maybe you have wrong imports,  I've added correct imports

Comment: well.can i use vector in parquet file instead of limit vector.val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000.parquet")